# Selecting all rows after a row with specific values without repeating the same subquery

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I have a table t1 and t2 which I join and order to form data set set1.

Two columns c1 and c2 form a unique identifier for the rows in set1.

I want to get all values from set1 after the first row with a specific c1 and c2.

I have a query like the one below which works, but it repeats the same subquery twice, which seems superfluous and overly complex even for Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c1, c3) myOrder, c1, c2, c3
  FROM t1, t2
  WHERE condition
  ORDER BY conditions
) sub1,
(
  SELECT sub1_again.myOrder FROM
  (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c1, c3) myOrder, c2, c3
    FROM t1, t2
    WHERE condition
    ORDER BY conditions
  ) sub1_again
  WHERE sub1_again.c2 = "foo" AND sub1_again.c3 = "bar"
) sub2
WHERE sub1.myOrder >= sub2.myOrder
ORDER BY sub1.myOrder
```

It seems like SQL would have a simple way to do this, but I am not sure what to search for.
Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c1, c3) myOrder, c2, c3
        ,CASE WHEN c2 = "foo" AND c3 = "bar"
              THEN row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c1, c3)
         END target_rn
  FROM t1, t2
  WHERE condition
  ORDER BY conditions
) WHERE myOrder > target_rn;
```

Comment: This is an answer to my question, though I ended up not using it because my real query (not the one I used above) derives the conditionals (c2 = "foo" AND c3 = "bar") from case statements, so using this example in my real and not over-simplified example would have required case statements within a case statement, which didn't end up looking much prettier.

Comment: The main principle, whatever you do, is to only run the main query once.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to work... Would't target_rn be equal to myOrder only once, and all the rest of the rows be NULL? How would the WHERE clause filter all the rows after the required one?

Comment: @Flavio `target_rn` will be equal to `myOrder` for all rows that match the condition in the `case` expression (i.e. those where `c2="foo" and c3="bar"`).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something missing in the accepted solution. However, it  helped me to come up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c1, c3) myOrder, c1, c2, c3,
    max(case when c2 = "foo" AND c3 = "bar" then 1 else 0 end) over (order by c1, c3) rowFound,
  FROM t1, t2
  WHERE condition
)
WHERE rowFound > 0
ORDER BY conditions
```

Basically the `case` is selecting which row is the one to start from, and the `max` "drags" the value from that row onwards. The last WHERE does the filtering.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to be more specific,if i understood well you have just to add the parameter 'where',like:`SELECT * FROM **where** element`